# Entity alias in new symfony 2.7 directory structure

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony-2.7

after adapting to new recommended structure in Symfony 2.7 I'm not able to access entity alias through `$em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')`.

This is my directory structure:

```
MyBundle
    - Component
        - Catalog
            - Model
                Product.php
```

And my mapping definitition in `config.yml`:

```
mappings:
    mybundle:
        type:      annotation
        dir:       %kernel.root_dir%/../src/mybundle/Component/Product/Model
        prefix:    MyBundle\Component\Product\Model
        alias:     ??? # I tried different things
```

What should I write in `$em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')` instead of `MyBundle:Product` to succesfully accesing the entity?

If possible I would like to use default Symfony alias, so I don't need to specify an alias for every entity in `config.yml`

Comment: Is there a reason to remove `auto_mapping` option? Normally if your bundle is registered properly, with auto_mapping enabled you should have no troubles using the short syntax no matter how you named your bundle. *Edit*: The following does not apply if you want to rename your bundle, but to keep using your old bundle name syntax.

Comment: Mmmh, I think I omitted that also, I mean, `generate:bundle`, I'm not doing so good with the new structure! :-P

Comment: I'll try to restart from bundle generation and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I didn't need `generate:bundle` as it's not a real bundle but a namespace and a logical organization of files.

The solution is to specify the complete namespace in `getRespository()`:

```
$em->getRepository('MyBundle\\Component\\Product\\Model\\CFGProduct)
```

Thanks